# Adjust iPhone accelerometer sensitivity?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to adjust the sensitivity of the iPhone's accelerometer?  I'm finding that it is too eager to switch back and forth between portrait and landscape mode, and am hoping that there is some way to adjust this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not a way to adjust the sensitivity of the accelerometer. Officially that is.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.  I went through all the settings and couldn't find anything, but thought I'd ask anyways...

Answer (score 2):

You can't adjust the sensitivity, but you can disable the auto-rotation if you have a jailbroken iPhone.

You may install **Rotation Inhibitor** in Cydia, see [here](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2009/06/rotation-inhibitor-sbsettings-toggle-allows-you-to-disable-accelerometer.html) for introduction.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the above if you use sbsettins you can add a rotation inhibitor toggle for easy on and off.